# Lodestar Becon Layer Error

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, consensus, genesis, beacon-nodes

I am trying to set up a beacon client for my private network, I got this error, `Error: First offset must equal to fixedEnd 2736633 != 2736653`.

What does this mean?

The `config.yaml` file for the beacon client is,

```
# Mainnet config

# Extends the mainnet preset
PRESET_BASE: 'mainnet'

# Free-form short name of the network that this configuration applies to - known
# canonical network names include:
# * 'mainnet' - there can be only one
# * 'mqube' - testnet
# Must match the regex: [a-z0-9\-]
CONFIG_NAME: 'mqube'

# Transition
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Estimated on Feb 16, 2024
TERMINAL_TOTAL_DIFFICULTY: 0
# By default, don't use these params
TERMINAL_BLOCK_HASH: 0x7bf37f55ef5fbc2403a3cadf26a091c3df872c52a5a534316e52198d4f300260
TERMINAL_BLOCK_HASH_ACTIVATION_EPOCH: 0



# Genesis
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# 8
MIN_GENESIS_ACTIVE_VALIDATOR_COUNT: 8
# Feb 16, 2024, 10am UTC
MIN_GENESIS_TIME: 1708077600
# Mainnet initial fork version, recommend altering for testnets
GENESIS_FORK_VERSION: 0x00677693
# 7200 seconds (2 hours)
GENESIS_DELAY: 7200


# Forking
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Some forks are disabled for now:
#  - These may be re-assigned to another fork-version later
#  - Temporarily set to max uint64 value: 2**64 - 1

# Altair
ALTAIR_FORK_VERSION: 0x01677693
ALTAIR_FORK_EPOCH: 0
# Bellatrix
BELLATRIX_FORK_VERSION: 0x02677693
BELLATRIX_FORK_EPOCH: 0
# Capella
CAPELLA_FORK_VERSION: 0x03677693
CAPELLA_FORK_EPOCH: 0


# Time parameters
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# 12 seconds
SECONDS_PER_SLOT: 12
# 14 (estimate from Eth1 mainnet)
SECONDS_PER_ETH1_BLOCK: 14
# 2**8 (= 256) epochs ~27 hours
MIN_VALIDATOR_WITHDRAWABILITY_DELAY: 256
# 2**8 (= 256) epochs ~27 hours
SHARD_COMMITTEE_PERIOD: 256
# 2**11 (= 2,048) Eth1 blocks ~8 hours
ETH1_FOLLOW_DISTANCE: 2048


# Validator cycle
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# 2**2 (= 4)
INACTIVITY_SCORE_BIAS: 4
# 2**4 (= 16)
INACTIVITY_SCORE_RECOVERY_RATE: 16
# 2**4 * 10**9 (= 16,000,000,000) Gwei
EJECTION_BALANCE: 16000000000
# 2**2 (= 4)
MIN_PER_EPOCH_CHURN_LIMIT: 4
# 2**16 (= 65,536)
CHURN_LIMIT_QUOTIENT: 65536

# Fork choice
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# 40%
PROPOSER_SCORE_BOOST: 40
# 20%
REORG_HEAD_WEIGHT_THRESHOLD: 20
# 160%
REORG_PARENT_WEIGHT_THRESHOLD: 160
# `2` epochs
REORG_MAX_EPOCHS_SINCE_FINALIZATION: 2


# Deposit contract
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Ethereum PoW Mainnet
DEPOSIT_CHAIN_ID: 10319988
DEPOSIT_NETWORK_ID: 10319988
DEPOSIT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: 0x0420420420420420420420420420420420420420


# Networking
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# `10 * 2**20` (= 10485760, 10 MiB)
GOSSIP_MAX_SIZE: 10485760
# `2**10` (= 1024)
MAX_REQUEST_BLOCKS: 1024
# `2**8` (= 256)
EPOCHS_PER_SUBNET_SUBSCRIPTION: 256
# `MIN_VALIDATOR_WITHDRAWABILITY_DELAY + CHURN_LIMIT_QUOTIENT // 2` (= 33024, ~5 months)
MIN_EPOCHS_FOR_BLOCK_REQUESTS: 33024
# `10 * 2**20` (=10485760, 10 MiB)
MAX_CHUNK_SIZE: 10485760
# 5s
TTFB_TIMEOUT: 5
# 10s
RESP_TIMEOUT: 10
ATTESTATION_PROPAGATION_SLOT_RANGE: 32
# 500ms
MAXIMUM_GOSSIP_CLOCK_DISPARITY: 500
MESSAGE_DOMAIN_INVALID_SNAPPY: 0x00000000
MESSAGE_DOMAIN_VALID_SNAPPY: 0x01000000
# 2 subnets per node
SUBNETS_PER_NODE: 2
# 2**8 (= 64)
ATTESTATION_SUBNET_COUNT: 64
ATTESTATION_SUBNET_EXTRA_BITS: 0
# ceillog2(ATTESTATION_SUBNET_COUNT) + ATTESTATION_SUBNET_EXTRA_BITS
ATTESTATION_SUBNET_PREFIX_BITS: 6
```

Please can anyone help? _/_

Thanks in advance! :)